# Error while connecting .net application to OrientDB on port 2424

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, orientdb, graph-databases

When I try to connect (run) the application from the visual studio 2015. I get the following error:

**"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond".**

The is the line for the error in the .net application is:

**OClient.CreateDatabasePool("localhost", 2424, "Test", ODatabaseType.Graph, "root", "admin", 3, "dummy");**

**- (I have a "Test" database and my password is "admin")**

The following are the logs are the finest level:

---

2016-06-15 13:05:54:705 CONFI Remote client connected from: OClientConnection [id=3, source=/127.0.0.1:58014, since=1466010354705] [OClientConnectionManager]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:705 FINE Request id:-1 type:2 [ONetworkProtocolBinary]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:705 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Reading string (4+N bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:705 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Read string: OrientDB-NET.binary [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:705 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Reading string (4+N bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:706 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Read string: 0.2.1 [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:706 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Reading short (2 bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:706 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Read short: 36 [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:706 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Reading string (4+N bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:707 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Read string: null [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:707 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Reading string (4+N bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:707 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Read string: ORecordDocument2csv [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:707 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Reading boolean (1 byte)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:708 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Read boolean: false [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:708 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Reading boolean (1 byte)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:708 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Read boolean: false [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:708 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Reading boolean (1 byte)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:709 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Read boolean: false [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:54:709 INFO /127.0.0.1:58014 - Reading string (4+N bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:58:443 FINE **I/O Error on client clientId=-1 reqType=2** [ONetworkProtocolBinary]
2016-06-15 13:05:58:444 INFO null possible previous close - Closing socket... [OChannelBinaryServer]
2016-06-15 13:05:58:735 FINE [OClientConnectionManager] found and removed pending closed channel 3 (null) [OClientConnectionManager]

---

**The firewall and antiviruses are disabled and no other service is running on port 2424.**

Could you guys help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO resolve this issue, use orientdb version 2.1.x. The latest version is currently not working with the .net API

Comment: They have updated the API and now the API works for orientdb 2.3 as well.